# Difficult to understand the acceleration of an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

This is the question I get confused:

Initially, the system of objects shown in Figure P5.93 is held motionless. The pulley and all surfaces and wheels are frictionless. Let the force F be zero and assume that m1 can move only vertically. At the instant after the system of objects is released, find

(a) the tension T in the string,

(b) the acceleration of m2,

(c) the acceleration of M, and

(d) the acceleration of m1.

(Note: The pulley accelerates along with the cart.)

[image]

I had a glimpse at the answer of the solution and it is like this:

[image]

[image]

a1 = a  is easy to understand.

But how did we know that M accelerates backward with acceleration A? And why is a2 equal to a - A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how did we know that M accelerates backward with acceleration A?

[image: Pulley FBD]

Drawing the FBD of the pulley, we can see that the tension force $T$ acts towards the left. since the pulley is connected to the block of mass $M$, hence the block accelerates towards the left with acceleration $a = \frac{T}{M}$

> why is a2 equal to a - A?

$a$ is the acceleration of the block of mass $m_2$ relative to the big block. when analyzing the situation in ground frame, the whole system including the 3 blocks accelerate towards the left with acceleration A.

Hence the net acceleration of the block would be $a-A$ towards the right.